# How can I get AWK to start reading by the end?

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, awk

I need to parse all a file into a better format to produce an outcome with columns delimited by a comma, thinking of being able to export the content in CSV file.

This is an example of my input;

```
.                                   D        0  Mon Dec 10 11:07:46 2018
..                                  D        0  Mon Feb 19 11:38:06 2018
RJ9-5                               D        0  Fri Nov 30 10:34:24 2018
WorkingOnClass                      D        0  Wed Feb 28 09:37:52 2018
ML-Test001                          D        0  Fri Dec  7 16:38:56 2018
TestML4Testing                      D        0  Wed Aug 22 08:58:42 2018
ML-NewDataSE SetCases1.xlsx         A  1415577  Wed Aug 29 14:00:16 2018
DR0001-Dum01                        D        0  Thu Aug 16 08:24:25 2018
DR0002-Dum02                        D        0  Thu Aug 16 09:04:50 2018
Readme File for Documentation And Data Description.docx      A    16136  Wed Aug 29 14:00:24 2018
ML Database Prototype               D        0  Thu Dec  6 15:11:11 2018
OneNote                             D        0  Mon Dec  3 09:39:20 2018
Data                                A        0  Mon Dec 10 11:07:46 2018

\RJ9-5
 .                                 D        0  Fri Nov 30 10:34:24 2018
 ..                                D        0  Mon Dec 10 11:07:46 2018
 KLR0151_Set023_Files_RJ9_05.xlsx  A   182462  Wed Apr  4 02:48:55 2018
 KLR0152_Set023_Files_RJ9_05.xlsx  A   525309  Wed Apr  4 02:53:57 2018

 \ML-Test001                          
 .                                   D        0  Wed Feb 28 09:37:52 2018
 ..                                  D        0  Mon Dec 10 11:07:46 2018
 WT_Conforming_Format1_1.docx        A   500914  Mon Feb 26 08:50:55 2018
 Conforming_Format_1_1.xlsx          A   130647  Mon Feb 26 08:52:33 2018
 DR0135_Dum01_text.xls               A   974848  Mon Feb 12 08:11:11 2018
 DR0139_Dum02_body.xls               A  1061888  Tue Jun 19 13:43:54 2018
 DataSet_File_mod0874953.xlsx        A   149835  Mon Feb 26 14:17:02 2018
 File Path For Dataset-2018.07.11.xlsx      A    34661  Mon Feb 12 09:27:17
```

This is script right here can make the job:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v OFS=, '
BEGIN { print "PATH, FILENAME, SIZE, TIMESTAMP" }
/[\\]/    { path=$0 }
$2 ~ /A/  {print path"\\"$1,$3,$4 " " $5 " " $6 " " $7 " "$8 }
' "$@"
```

But is ignoring the names with spaces on it, so I need to validate them with something like:

```
awk -v FS="\t" '{print $1}'
```

But I could't integrate into the shell script, because the way the shell script is working, so I was thinking on make AWK to start reading by the end, since the end is always the same, and leave the rest.

The output should something like this:

```
/RJ9-5/KLR0151_Set023_Files_RJ9_05.xlsx,182462,Wed Apr  4 02:48:55 2018
/RJ9-5/KLR0152_Set023_Files_RJ9_05.xlsx,25309,Wed Apr  4 02:53:57 2018
/ML-Test001/WT_Conforming_Format1_1.docx,500914,Mon Feb 26 08:50:55 2018
/ML-Test001/Format_1_1.xlsx,130647,Mon Feb 26 08:52:33 2018
/ML-Test001/DR0135_Dum01_text.xls,974848,Mon Feb 12 08:11:11 2018
/ML-Test001/DR0139_Dum02_body.xls,1061888,Tue Jun 19 13:43:54 2018
/ML-Test001/DataSet_File_mod0874953.xlsx,149835,Mon Feb 26 14:17:02 2018
/ML-Test001/File Path For Dataset-2018.07.11.xlsx,34661,Mon Feb 12 09:27:17 2018
```

Comment: Use `$NF`, `$(NF-1)`, etc....

Comment: I gather you're not using a unix-like operating system, but [this](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) is still probably good advice. If you're using bash anyway, it'll likely be safer to use "Pathname Expansion" (which you can read about in the man page) to collect your filenames, then use your operating system's version of the [stat](http://man.freebsd.org/stat) command, whatever that is.

Comment: your input is not matching with what you are doing in the script... please review

Comment: [edit] your question to add the expected output given that input.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()` (and far less importantly `\s` shorthand for `[[:space:]]`):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="," }
{ gsub(/^\s+|\s+$/,"") }
sub(/^\\/,"/") { path = $0; next }
path == "" { next }
match($0,/^(.*[^ ]) +A +([^ ]+) +(.*)/,a) { print path "/" a[1], a[2], a[3] }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
/RJ9-5/KLR0151_Set023_Files_RJ9_05.xlsx,182462,Wed Apr  4 02:48:55 2018
/RJ9-5/KLR0152_Set023_Files_RJ9_05.xlsx,525309,Wed Apr  4 02:53:57 2018
/ML-Test001/WT_Conforming_Format1_1.docx,500914,Mon Feb 26 08:50:55 2018
/ML-Test001/Conforming_Format_1_1.xlsx,130647,Mon Feb 26 08:52:33 2018
/ML-Test001/DR0135_Dum01_text.xls,974848,Mon Feb 12 08:11:11 2018
/ML-Test001/DR0139_Dum02_body.xls,1061888,Tue Jun 19 13:43:54 2018
/ML-Test001/DataSet_File_mod0874953.xlsx,149835,Mon Feb 26 14:17:02 2018
/ML-Test001/File Path For Dataset-2018.07.11.xlsx,34661,Mon Feb 12 09:27:17
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the first character "/" from the output at the beggining?

Comment: Of course but then it wouldn’t look like the output you said you wanted in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Perl solution:

```
$ perl -lane ' if(/^\s*$/) { $x=0;$y=0} if(/^\\/) {$x=1 ;($a=$_)=~s/\s*$//g;$a=~s/\\/\//g; } $y++ if $x==1 ; if($y>3) { s/^\s*//g; $_=~s/(.+?)\s+\S+\s+((\d+)\s+.+)/$1 $2/g;print "$a/$_" } ' essparaq.txt
/RJ9-5/KLR0151_Set023_Files_RJ9_05.xlsx 182462  Wed Apr  4 02:48:55 2018
/RJ9-5/KLR0152_Set023_Files_RJ9_05.xlsx 525309  Wed Apr  4 02:53:57 2018
/ML-Test001/WT_Conforming_Format1_1.docx 500914  Mon Feb 26 08:50:55 2018
/ML-Test001/Conforming_Format_1_1.xlsx 130647  Mon Feb 26 08:52:33 2018
/ML-Test001/DR0135_Dum01_text.xls 974848  Mon Feb 12 08:11:11 2018
/ML-Test001/DR0139_Dum02_body.xls 1061888  Tue Jun 19 13:43:54 2018
/ML-Test001/DataSet_File_mod0874953.xlsx 149835  Mon Feb 26 14:17:02 2018
/ML-Test001/File Path For Dataset-2018.07.11.xlsx 34661  Mon Feb 12 09:27:17

$ cat essparaq.txt
.                                   D        0  Mon Dec 10 11:07:46 2018
..                                  D        0  Mon Feb 19 11:38:06 2018
RJ9-5                               D        0  Fri Nov 30 10:34:24 2018
WorkingOnClass                      D        0  Wed Feb 28 09:37:52 2018
ML-Test001                          D        0  Fri Dec  7 16:38:56 2018
TestML4Testing                      D        0  Wed Aug 22 08:58:42 2018
ML-NewDataSE SetCases1.xlsx         A  1415577  Wed Aug 29 14:00:16 2018
DR0001-Dum01                        D        0  Thu Aug 16 08:24:25 2018
DR0002-Dum02                        D        0  Thu Aug 16 09:04:50 2018
Readme File for Documentation And Data Description.docx      A    16136  Wed Aug 29 14    :00:24 2018
ML Database Prototype               D        0  Thu Dec  6 15:11:11 2018
OneNote                             D        0  Mon Dec  3 09:39:20 2018
Data                                A        0  Mon Dec 10 11:07:46 2018

\RJ9-5
 .                                 D        0  Fri Nov 30 10:34:24 2018
 ..                                D        0  Mon Dec 10 11:07:46 2018
 KLR0151_Set023_Files_RJ9_05.xlsx  A   182462  Wed Apr  4 02:48:55 2018
 KLR0152_Set023_Files_RJ9_05.xlsx  A   525309  Wed Apr  4 02:53:57 2018

\ML-Test001
 .                                   D        0  Wed Feb 28 09:37:52 2018
 ..                                  D        0  Mon Dec 10 11:07:46 2018
 WT_Conforming_Format1_1.docx        A   500914  Mon Feb 26 08:50:55 2018
 Conforming_Format_1_1.xlsx          A   130647  Mon Feb 26 08:52:33 2018
 DR0135_Dum01_text.xls               A   974848  Mon Feb 12 08:11:11 2018
 DR0139_Dum02_body.xls               A  1061888  Tue Jun 19 13:43:54 2018
 DataSet_File_mod0874953.xlsx        A   149835  Mon Feb 26 14:17:02 2018
 File Path For Dataset-2018.07.11.xlsx      A    34661  Mon Feb 12 09:27:17
```